# How to fix Error ManyToMany in @RestController?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm an entity Story:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "story", schema = "")
@Data
public class Story implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "sID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long sID;
    @Column(name = "vnName", nullable = false)
    private String vnName;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "_scategory",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "sID", nullable = false)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "cID", nullable = false)})
    private List<Category> categoryList;
}
```

And Entity Category:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category", schema = "", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"cMetatitle"}),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"cName"})})
@Data
public class Category implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "cID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer cID;
    @Column(name = "cName", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 150)
    private String cName;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categoryList")
    private List<Story> storyList;
}
```

But when I grab the Story in RestController, I get the following error message:

> WARN http-nio-8080-exec-9
>   o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:234 - Failure while trying
>   to resolve exception
>   [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException]
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the
>   response has been committed

Can anybody show me how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: I don't see relevant code - warn comes from controller.

Comment: I do not see any field cMetatitle that you put in constrain unique in any class ! is that normal ?

Comment: Else you can add to your application.properties : debug=true and you scheck your created tables how they look like

Comment: I have dropping a fields when writing to allow more code in the post